# Change colour palette of an image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, rgb

I'm trying to write a program to convert the colour palette of an image to a custom predetermined palette.
Unfortunately its not working and I think the problem is with how I'm converting the colours. For it I'm just comparing the RGB value of each pixel to the RGB values of the custom palette and then replacing the pixel colour with the RGB with the least difference to the original RGB value.

```py
import PIL, math, numpy
from colormap import hex2rgb
from colormap import rgb2hex
from PIL import Image

rgb_pallete_r, rgb_pallete_g, rgb_pallete_b = [], [], [] # creates list for the rgb values of the custom palette
hex_pallete = list(colour_map) # creates list of all the hex values from the palette
for i in range(0,len(hex_pallete)): # adds the individual rgb for each palette colour to there respective list 
  rgb_pallete_r.append(hex2rgb(hex_pallete[i])[0])
  rgb_pallete_g.append(hex2rgb(hex_pallete[i])[1])
  rgb_pallete_b.append(hex2rgb(hex_pallete[i])[2])
  
def convert_image(path, height, width):

  colour = []
  image = Image.open(path) # load image using PIL
  new_image = image.resize((width,height)) # resize image so it is the desired height and width in pixels 
  
  for x in range(width): # loops through all the pixels on the x axis
   for y in range(height): # loops though all the pixels on the y axis 
       r,g,b = new_image.getpixel((x,y)) # gets r g b colour value for the pixel

       colour.append(r),colour.append(g),colour.append(b) # add r g b value to respecctive list for later
       new_image.putpixel((x,y), replace_colour(r,g,b)) # replaces pixel with new colour
        
  result = new_image.resize(image.size,Image.NEAREST) # resizes image to orginal size
  result.show() # shows image

def replace_colour(r,g,b):


  holding_colours, log = [], [] #holds all the distances and there index

  hex_pallete = list(colour_map) #gets the hex values of the colours from the dictorary
  for i in range(0,len(hex_pallete)): # loops through all the colour in the pallete   
    distance = math.sqrt(abs((rgb_pallete_r[i]-r)^2+(rgb_pallete_g[i]-g)^2+(rgb_pallete_b[i]-b)^2)) # calculates distance from pixel rgb to pallete rgb
    holding_colours.append(distance) # adds the distance to a list 
    log.append(i) # adds there index to a seperate list 

  new_colour = numpy.argmin(holding_colours) # return the smallest distance 
  print(rgb_pallete_r[new_colour], rgb_pallete_g[new_colour], rgb_pallete_b[new_colour])# for debugging
  return rgb_pallete_r[new_colour], rgb_pallete_g[new_colour], rgb_pallete_b[new_colour]# returns the new rgb
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong but I think its either where I'm calculating the distance or when I'm returning the values.